Adding a background image for signature Okular
I'd like to add an image to my signature. I've generated a certificate using Open-SSL, and it works. However, the signature in Okular repeats the name when I'd expect to be able to put my handwritten signature (and have the signed by ... on date ...)
Without background image:

With background image (the hand written signature):


I think you may need to have two different signatures to do this. The text info is the data from your certificate and is the "verifiable" signature. The picture is just a picture and doesn't really prove anything in a digital world. Have you checked the Okular documentation to see whether it has options for signature display that may alleviate this?

The only info I found is here: https://docs.kde.org/stable5/en/okular/okular/signatures.html
It says it uses the Poppler lib... That's about it. I understand that the picture is meaningless, but the digital signature isn't. I'd skip the duplicate name and just have the mention it has been signed by...  on date ...
